# Upgrade Magento 1.8 to 1.9 - Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection()

Tags: php, magento, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade our Magento 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.2.1.

I copied the db to another table so I could do a test run first.
I uploaded 1.9 files to ourdomain.com/upgrade, then copied every extra installed module.

In our database I changed the base secure and unsecure url to ourdomain.com/upgrade.

Now when I go to ourdomain.com/upgrade I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object in /home/domains/ourdomain.com/public_html/upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 134

I have pasted this above line 134: `echo get_class($this);exit;`
and now have this:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that before the line
`$this->setConnection($this->getResource()->getReadConnection());`
put
`if(!is_object($this->getResource())){
    var_dump($this -> _resourceModel);die();
}`
to find out which resouce model generates your problem.

gl & hf

p.s. I think it's going to be the sales/order ;), I have the same problem with it.